# How to merge two tables in mongo db and perform comparison and logical operation on the resultant data using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I'm new to MongoDB and node/express. I have two schemas(books and courses)which are sharing the same userId value. I want to merge the tables and perform the comparison operation query( eq,ne, nin, not, etc) on the result data. so that my result value keeps changes based on the query I pass. I'm able to do it individually for both documents. but I want to perform the combined operation

For example one courses schema has many books. If I select a course from the course collection it should give me the list of books from the book collection and later I need to select one course and books and at the end add to the cart.

Is there any way of using loops I can get the data bypassing the userId value which is common in both the collections?

Also I have tried with lookup and populate aggregation. In both cases, I'm able to perform query operations on only one collection. I need to perform a join on both collections.

Here is the code:
Collections:

```
const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   CousrseId : {type:String},
   student_id:{type:String},
   student_name: {type:String},
   class_time:{type:string},
   class_days:{type:String}
   
   const course = mongoose.model('course' , CourseSchema)
module.exports = course;

const BooksSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       CousrseId : {type:String},
       student_id:{type:String},
       Book_name: {type:String},
       
       
       const Books = mongoose.model('books' , BooksSchema)
    module.exports = Books;
```

Now I need to perform operations on both collections

```
  const queryObj = {...req.query}; 
  const excludedFields = ['page','sort','limit','fields'];
  excludedFields.forEach(el => delete queryObj[el])
  let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObj)   
  queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt|ne|eq|in|not)\b/g, match => `$${match}`);
```

From here I'm not able to figure out how can I do. I tried lookup and population but I need to perform the operation on combined Json result data.

Comment: You are probably looking for the aggregate framework. That doesn't a join on two documents and you can further pipe additional operations.

Comment: I have used an aggregate framework. But not able to perform operational quires on both the joined documents.  Could you elaborate, please? Thank you

Comment: I'll need code. Examples of both documents and the desired results

Comment: You can find the code above.  Thank you